# How to remove \BODY defined in the algorithmic package?

Tags: macros, environments, incompatibility, algorithmic

The `algorithmic` package defines a command `\BODY` which evidently clashes when used in conjunction with the `environ` package. More specifically, LaTeX failes to compile when an `algorithmic` environment is used inside another environment created using `\NewEnviron`. How can I undo, or rename, the `\BODY` which is provided by the `algorithmic` package?

Comment: Can you provide a MWE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy the command using `\let`.

```
\let\ALGBODY\BODY
```

You can delete the definition using by letting it to `\relax`.

```
\let\BODY\relax
```

Of course, there will be trouble if other packages expect to find the `\BODY` command as defined by `algorithmic`.