# NewEnviron, \BODY and lstlisting

Tags: listings, environments

I was trying to understand egreg's answer to [Hide content to show later](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220387/hide-content-to-show-later/220389?noredirect=1#comment607009_220389), and I noticed that there were some problems when using `lstlisting` or `tcblisting` environments inside the `solution` environment proposed by egreg, while other environments like `figure`or `proof` seem to work fine.

I looked to several related questions (like [Using an environ environment with \newenvironment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78692/using-an-environ-environment-with-newenvironment) and [How to remove \BODY defined in the algorithmic package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131279/how-to-remove-body-defined-in-the-algorithmic-package)), and I think (but am not sure) that the conflict comes from the `listing` package which possibly defines a `\BODY` command, as does `environ`.

For example, a minimal non working example is the following :

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{listings}

\NewEnviron{solution}{\BODY}

\begin{document}

\begin{solution}
This is an environment containing code.
\begin{lstlisting}
My code
\end{lstlisting} 
\end{solution}


\end{document}
```

With this code, I have the following error : Text dropped after begin of listing

Where does this error comes from, and how can I avoid it ? 
My goal would be to have a `solution` environment, defined with `\NewEnviron`, and which could contain an `lstlisting`or a `tcblisting` environment.

Note : I am aware that in the code I have defined, I could use `\newenvironment` instead of `\NewEnviron`, but the environment I want (which is exactly the one in egreg's answer to [Hide content to show later](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220387/hide-content-to-show-later/220389?noredirect=1#comment607009_220389)) really needs the features of `\NewEnviron`, especially the `\BODY` macro, since I want to store the content of `\solution` in order to display it later.

Comment: You can't have verbatim material like `lstlisting` inside of another command. Environments defined with `environ` *look* like environments but in many aspects *behave* like commands => you can't have verbatim material in an environment defined with `environ`

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131546

Comment: Thanks a lot, my guess for the origin of the problem was wrong, and I realize that my question is a total duplicate. (For the sake of completeness, the solution uses `\cprotectEnv`).

Comment: An alternative solution with `tcolorboxes` and `tcblistings` can be found in   http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/257455/1952

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to settle for `verbatim` code that is not syntax highlighted, and which does not require page breaking, you could place it in a `verbatimbox` prior to entering your newly defined `solution` environment.

Of course, by that point, it is in a box, and not available as text.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{environ}
%\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\NewEnviron{solution}{\BODY}

\begin{document}

\begin{verbbox}
c My code
      i = 0
      do while(i .lt. 10)
        print *, i
        i = i + 1
      end do
      stop
\end{verbbox}
\begin{solution}
This is an environment containing code.

\theverbbox
\end{solution}


\end{document}
```

[image]